# How do I add calendar dates to an existing data table so that an entire month is accounted for in R?

Tags: r

I need to "back-fill" dates for a 3 year time period (2016-2018) and
My actual data has over 32,000 observations and is a table of dates, countries, regions within a country, and protests and riot events.

For simplicity, let's say the data is limited to the month January with 3 countries. I want to eventually do a lagged data panel, but to do so I need all of the dates for the time period accounted for (I think).

```
DT <- data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-12", "2019-01-08" )),
             Country = c("India","India","India","Pakistan","Pakistan", "Cameroon", "India"),
             Region = c('Kashmir', 'Rajasthan', 'Punjab', 'Islamabad', 'National', 'Nord-Ouest', "Kashmir"),
             Protest = c(4,2,0,1,4,1,0 ),
             Riot = c(0,2,1,1,4,1,1 ))

# Date  Country     Region Protest Riot
# 1: 2019-01-01    India    Kashmir       4    0
# 2: 2019-01-01    India  Rajasthan       2    2
# 3: 2019-01-01    India     Punjab       0    1
# 4: 2019-01-01 Pakistan  Islamabad       1    1
# 5: 2019-01-01 Pakistan   National       4    4
# 6: 2019-01-12 Cameroon Nord-Ouest       1    1
# 7: 2019-01-08    India    Kashmir       0    1
```

I could make and merge a new data table with dates for the month of January and count out the number of repetitions for each country, but that is not feasible for 32 Countries and their regions. Is there a way to account for countries having different numbers of entry for any given date and then filling in rows so that (in this case) each country and region would have a date represented for everyday of the month? a desired output would be along the lines of:

```
# Date  Country     Region Protest Riot
# 1: 2019-01-01    India    Kashmir       4    0
# 2: 2019-01-01    India  Rajasthan       2    2
# 3: 2019-01-01    India     Punjab       0    1
# 4: 2019-01-01 Pakistan  Islamabad       1    1
# 5: 2019-01-01 Pakistan   National       4    4
# 6: 2019-01-01 Cameroon Nord-Ouest       NA   NA
# 7: 2019-01-02    India    Kashmir       NA   NA
# 8: 2019-01-02    India  Rajasthan       NA   NA
# 9: 2019-01-02    India     Punjab       NA   Na
# 10: 2019-01-02 Pakistan  Islamabad      NA   NA
# 11: 2019-01-02 Pakistan   National      NA   NA
# 12: 2019-01-02 Cameroon Nord-Ouest      NA   NA
```

Comment: is the expected output values correct/

Comment: Do you need `library(tidyverse);> DT %>% complete(Date, Country, Region) %>% arrange(Date, is.na(Protest))`

Comment: Also, the `2019-01-12`  for 6th row seems like a typo?

Comment: the 2019-01-12 wasn't a typo, I was just meant to show that there are gaps of data from a dates standpoint, sorry for the confusion. This didn't quite work either, when I tried your suggestion it didn't keep country and region matched. so line 6 once you run it has "Islamabad" matched with "Cameroon," which would throw off the data.
    Date            Country       Region     Protest  Riot
6: 2019-01-01 Cameroon Islamabad       NA    NA

Comment: @kss54. I had a sslightly different answer below.  Having said that are you creating days or "month", if it is day, then `by = "day"` in the code

Comment: Sorry, may be i missed the relevant info

Comment: it's by days, I just randomly had the month of January in hope a smaller example could be used for my larger problem.

Comment: So are you dropping the row 6 and 7 in the expanded one `2019-01-12` `2019-01-08`

Comment: May be a group by `complete` `DT %>% group_by(Country, Region) %>% complete(Date = seq(min(.$Date), max(.$Date), by = 'day'))%>% ungroup %>% arrange(Date)`

Comment: I'm not dropping observations, but in the DT example, jan 12th, Cameroon:Norde-Ouest on line 6 and there are no Cameroon:Nord-Ouest dates prior to that, so I need all of the dates backfilled for it. so that Jan, 1-11th in this case have  entries for it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you try the code I commented just now

Comment: just tried it and its adding more entries than need be for the date, I think due to the regions still mismatching.

Comment: If you check the first 10 values I printed, isn't that the same as your expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be we can use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>% 
   mutate_if(is.character, ~ factor(., levels = unique(.))) %>% 
   group_by(Country, Region) %>%
   complete(Date = seq(min(.$Date), max(.$Date), by = 'day')) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   arrange(Date) %>%
   head(12)
# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   Country  Region     Date       Protest  Riot
#   <fct>    <fct>      <date>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 India    Kashmir    2019-01-01       4     0
# 2 India    Rajasthan  2019-01-01       2     2
# 3 India    Punjab     2019-01-01       0     1
# 4 Pakistan Islamabad  2019-01-01       1     1
# 5 Pakistan National   2019-01-01       4     4
# 6 Cameroon Nord-Ouest 2019-01-01      NA    NA
# 7 India    Kashmir    2019-01-02      NA    NA
# 8 India    Rajasthan  2019-01-02      NA    NA
# 9 India    Punjab     2019-01-02      NA    NA
#10 Pakistan Islamabad  2019-01-02      NA    NA
#11 Pakistan National   2019-01-02      NA    NA
#12 Cameroon Nord-Ouest 2019-01-02      NA    NA
```

Comment: similar to the suggestions above, your suggestions doesn't keep Country and Region accounted for, so the they are being mismatched, as if its cycling them independently, such as India now have Islamabad next to it or Nord-Ouest, which are for different countries

Comment: I think there was conflict messing up my results from yours, after restarting R and reloading Tiddyverse this worked, thank you!